# How to make a List Item the same height as the parent div?

Tags: html, css

```
<nav>
<ul id="navUl">
    <li>
        <div class="settingsDiv">
            hey
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

What I want to do is set the div's height to 100% so that it'll be whatever height the nav is.

Comment: Can you show us your CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say what you've done wrong - because you didn't supply your CSS code.

But here is a working copy of what you're asking: http://jsfiddle.net/WDAXp/2/

You need to set `<nav>`'s height, then set `#navUl`, `#navUl li`, and `settingsDiv` height to 100%.

**edit**

oops, didn't read the question properly. fixed it.

Comment: That's not true. You set the li to `50px`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the nav some fixed height, and the others inherit from the parent.

```
nav {
    height: 100px;
}
ul, li, .settingsDiv {
    height: inherit;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Deten/)